# Magento 2 : Get product price including tax in order confirmation email

Tags: magento2, product, sales-order, tax

Is their any way to Get product price including tax in order confirmation email ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Can you explain your requirement?

Comment: In a customized order confirmation email template, there is customization that displays ordered products, but the price for that products is not tax included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help

Create helper class

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
     /**
     * Order Item Repository
     *
     * @var OrderItemRepositoryInterface
     */
     private $orderItemRepository;

     public function __construct(
        OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemRepository
     ) {
        $this->orderItemRepository = $orderItemRepository;
     }

     /**
     * Get price including tax
     */
    public function getPriceInclTaxByItemId($itemId)
    {
        return $this->orderItemRepository->get($itemId);
    }
```

In phtml file

```
/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item         = $block->getItem();

$ordered_item_id = $_item->getOrderItemId() ? $_item->getOrderItemId() : $_item->getId();

$itemPrice = $helper->getPriceInclTaxByItemId($ordered_item_id);
```

Comment: Can you give me more details, like which phmtl? it will reflect in bundle item order confirmatilon email ?